# MySQL - Massive structural changes

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database that has references in nearly every table to the "user" table to track things like who last created or updated a record. Unfortunately, the user table's primary key is "username", rather than an auto incremented id. We have frequent situations where a username needs to change because of typos or changes in the user profile, and this is really time-consuming under the current design.

I want to change the structure to use an auto-incremented id, but am not finding an easy way to do it. In SqlServer, I could use a combination of introspection on references, cursors, and structural changes to do this without much effort. But from what I've read about MySQL, I (1) can only use loops from WITHIN a stored procedure and (2) can only change structure from OUTSIDE a stored procedure.

The only option I've found is the pretty tedious task of
(1) Creating a temporary table to find references to username:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS username_refs as (select table_name, column_name, constraint_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name from information_schema.key_column_usage where REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'user' and referenced_column_name = 'username');
```

(2) Building up the set of SQL statements to accomplish each task. For example, this creates a "shadow" column on each table that references username:

```
select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ADD COLUMN `', column_name,'_2` bigint(20) ;') from username_refs;
```

This ends up being hundreds of lines of sql. Is there an easier way to accomplish this that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people prefer to write a script in an external language to loop over the tables and format the desired ALTER TABLE statements. For example, whatever you preference is of Perl, Ruby, PHP, Python, etc. Every scripting language supports an API to access MySQL.

What you're doing is fine too. You can use SQL to generate the list of ALTER statements, save the output of that to a file, and then run the file as an SQL script.

By the way, you don't necessarily need a separate auto-increment key. You define your foreign keys to `username` so as to ON UPDATE CASCADE. See "Referential Actions" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: I would not promote the last option with cascading.  That is a poor design and can greatly hinder performance in any type of production system.  If he can fix it, which is what he is trying to do, then I would push for that.

Comment: @tsells, that's a fair point, making *every* table take cascading changes when a username changes is expensive.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yes, now that I think of it a scripting language probably would have been less tedious. But I'm most of the way down this path now. I was just surprised there wasn't an easier way in sql.